# Are isolated singularities always cone-like?

Tags: algebraic-topology, singularity-theory

Assume $(X,x_0)$ is a pointed topological space such that $X \backslash\{x_0\}$ is a manifold. Does there always exist a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ which is homeomorphic to the cone $cN := (0,1]\times N/(1,u)\sim(1,v)$ over a manifold $N$?

I am not interested in issues that come from the failure of Hausdorffness as e.g. with the line with two origins. So I'm happy to assume that $X$ itself is Hausdorff or even compact.

---

I can think of two kinds of examples for $(X,x_0)$ which   don't come from artifically attaching a cone to a manifold:

- The wedge sum of two manifolds. In that case there  is always a neigbourhood around the wedge point, which is homeomorphic to $c(S^n\coprod S^n)$.
- Spaces $(X,x_0)=(Y/A,A/A)$ for $Y$ a compact manifold and $A\subset Y$ a closed subset. For example the [pinched torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinched_torus) has this form, but yet again there is neighbourhood homeomorphic to $c(S^1 \coprod S^1).$ I can imagine that bad things happen when $A$ is really wild, but I couldn't produce a counterexample this way. (Taking a Cantor set inside a circle should leave us with a countable bouquet of circles (?) and hence a wedge sum.)

---

**Motivation:**
In the context of singular Riemannian manifolds (e.g. in J.Cheegers paper "[on the spectral geometry of spaces with cone-like singularities](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC383544/pdf/pnas00005-0021.pdf)") one studies singularities as above and uses the the term *cone-like* for a  Riemannian metric that has a particular form under the identification $U\backslash\{x_0\} \cong cN \backslash\{\text{cone-tip}\}$. In all references that I have seen in this context, it is first assumed that $U\cong cN$ exists, before the metric is specified and I am wondering whether this is an actual restriction on the local topology of $X$ around $x_0$ or comes automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring)? It is the space consisting of all the circles in the plane with radius $\frac1n$ and center at $(\frac1n, 0)$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ (meaning they all touch at the origin).

Removing the origin makes the space into a disjoint union of open line segments, which is a manifold. But any neighbourhood of the origin will contain infinitely many of the circles, and is therefore not a cone.

Comment: Shame on me! How can I ask for a counterexample in topology without thinking about the Hawaiian earring first? Thanks!

Comment: I've decided to open the question again, because I  hope to see a higher dimensional example. (After all, I am interested in analysis on $X\backslash \{x_0\}$, which is boring otherwise.)

Comment: @jabo The Hawaiian earring generalizes quite readily to any dimension.